# Traverse existing std priority queue in reverse order

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

I am working on a c++ project using std::priority queue objects. I want at some point of the code to access the priority queue in reverse order(from the bottom to the top), my naive solution is to pop all the element in a new array and store them in reverse order.
I'm wondering if there's a more optimized away to traverse the priority queue in reverse order?

Comment: The container which `priority_queue` takes is `protected` so you can extend the `priority_queue` class and do what you want with it's container.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::priority_queue` is not a container, it is a container adaptor. If you want to observe the elements, the best way is to subclass it and expose the members of the underlying container.

```
template<class T, class Container = std::vector<T>, class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>> 
class my_priority_queue : std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare> {
    using priority_queue::priority_queue;
    typename Container::const_iterator begin() const { return c.begin(); }
    typename Container::const_iterator end() const { return c.end(); }
    typename Container::const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return c.rbegin(); }
    typename Container::const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return c.rend(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Caleth, but still got  a compilation problem with the code,                                                         /tmp/lpaTtDhkeM.cpp:9:63: error: 'c' was not declared in this scope
    9 |     typename Container::const_iterator begin() const { return c.begin(); }